# Why is hard coded arabic letter not having same value as Unicode code point

Tags: linux, perl, unicode

I got this code to handle arabic text, it's demonstrating my question:

```
my $noon = "ن";
my $code_point = charinfo(ord($noon))->{'code'};
print "Unicode code point for 'ن' (noon): U+$code_point\n";

$noon = "\N{U+0646}";
$code_point = sprintf("%04X", ord($noon));
print "Unicode code point for 'ن' (noon): U+$code_point\n";
$noon_code = 0x0646;
print (chr($noon_code), "\n");
```

It prints out:

```
Unicode code point for 'ن' (noon): U+00D9
Unicode code point for 'ن' (noon): U+0646
Wide character in print at code.pl line 11.
ن
```

The values are different. I used Linux Mint text editor (Xed).
It seems I can't use hard-coded Arabic when coding, but I have used text files, they have letters with correct values.

Comment: `U+0646` is Unicode, `0xD9` is in the [ANSI Codepage-720](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_720) and is not Unicode.  You have a locale mismatch.

Comment: Right.  Your source file is evidently not in UTF-8.  It's in code page 720, which means it probably came from a Windows system.

Comment: I promise, it was only Linux, but... maybe it can be changed in the Xed settings.

Comment: Weird 8-bit legacy code pages are _usually_ only found on Windows these days; but it's not like you can't misconfigure Linux - you just need to try harder. The simple and, these days, ubiquitous solution is to make sure you configure everything to use UTF-8. This is already the default out of the box on Linux for the vast majority of distros and utilities. Probably file a bug if you find one which doesn't obey your locale settings; and of course, make sure you configure your locale to use UTF-8.

Comment: @tripleee, Tim Roberts, That's quite a stretch. It's far more likely to be UTF-8. D9 is the first byte of the UTF-8 for ن

Comment: I didn't know about the codepage-720 and its Windows counterpart 1256. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said you provided the following:

```perl
my $noon = "ن";
```

But you actually provided the two characters 0xD9 and 0x86, something equivalent to the following:

```perl
my $noon = "\xD9\x86";
```

This is because you told Perl the script is encoded using ASCII. (String and regex literals are 8-bit clean, though, meaning bytes 0x80 to 0xFF result in those characters with those values.) But the script is actually encoded using UTF-8. You need to add `use utf8;` to tell this to Perl.

You also need encode your output since STDOUT expects bytes by default. You could do that by using `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`.

Comment: Thank you. Now that I've added use utf8; what do I "provide" instead of "\xD9\x86" - and even if output of 16-bit characters go fine after use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)' - is the input still in bytes, or do the input go 16-bits?

Comment: The first correction - use utf8 - made the reading from my script file work perfect. The second correction - use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)' - made the warning at runtime go away.

Comment: Equivalent to `"\x{646}"` with `use utf8;`. // It's not 16 bits. Unicode chars require 21 bits, and Perl characters are 32 or 64 bits in size (depending on the build)